# How to remove unwanted Emmet Abbreviation in vs code autoComplete suggestion

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, styled-components

How to remove default value in  Emmet Abbreviation suggestion?

For example, I want `background-color : ;` instead of `background-color:#fff;`
need to manually remove the color and type the color I actually want every time

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Just disable the css emmet extension you've installed.

Comment: Although not explicitly stated by the original poster, they probably only want to change unwanted behavior but not uninstall the features completely.